# cbind two output tables in one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

i have two tables. 
The first

```
  char    1         2    
  <fct> <chr>    <chr>   
1 mild   2(2.00%) 2(2.00%)
2 moder  2(2.00%) 2(2.00%)
```

and the second

```
  char  `1               `2`
  <fct> <chr>           <chr>       
1 mild   7 (25.00%)      7 (25.00%)  
2 moder  7 (25.00%)      7 (25.00%)
```

I want to combine this tables in one.
Namely, as output i expect

```
char      1                      2
<fct>   <chr>     Y             <chr>          Y
mild   7(25.00%) 2(2.00%)      7(25.00%)    2(2.00%)
moder  7(25.00%) 2(2.00%)      7(25.00%)    2(2.00%)
```

How to do it?

Comment: Are you able to show how you're producing these two tables? It's not quite clear to me from the output how they're laid out.

Answer (score 2):

cbinding data frames like this can be unsafe, I would recommend a full join instead :

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="char", all = TRUE)
df3[c("char",sort(names(df3)[-1]))]
#    char       1.x        1.y       2.x        2.y
# 1  mild 2 (2.00%) 7 (25.00%) 2 (2.00%) 7 (25.00%)
# 2 moder 2 (2.00%) 7 (25.00%) 2 (2.00%) 7 (25.00%)
```

Comment: Yeah, column binding assumes the rows are ordered identically (inlike bind_rows, which can concatenate identically-named columns that aren't in the same order). This is a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your two tables look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = data_frame(
  char = factor(c('mild', 'moder')),
  `1` = c('2 (2.00%)', '2 (2.00%)'),
  `2` = c('2 (2.00%)', '2 (2.00%)'))
df2 = data_frame(
  char = factor(c('mild', 'moder')),
  `1` = c('7 (25.00%)', '7 (25.00%)'),
  `2` = c('7 (25.00%)', '7 (25.00%)'))

# using base R
cbind(df1, df2)
#>    char         1         2  char          1          2
#> 1  mild 2 (2.00%) 2 (2.00%)  mild 7 (25.00%) 7 (25.00%)
#> 2 moder 2 (2.00%) 2 (2.00%) moder 7 (25.00%) 7 (25.00%)

# using tidyverse
bind_cols(df1, df2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   char  `1`       `2`       char1 `11`       `21`      
#>   <fct> <chr>     <chr>     <fct> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 mild  2 (2.00%) 2 (2.00%) mild  7 (25.00%) 7 (25.00%)
#> 2 moder 2 (2.00%) 2 (2.00%) moder 7 (25.00%) 7 (25.00%)
```

I'd recommend the tidyverse one, since you won't end up with repeated column names (which'll really mess up further operations on this data), but you'll probably want to `setNames` on it regardless.

Comment: this is good and simple solution. But! output 1 mild  2 (2.00%) 2 (2.00%) mild  7 (25.00%) 7 (25.00%) , can you restructure the output  to mild   7(25.00%) 2(2.00%)      7(25.00%)    2(2.00%)

Comment: I'd maybe edit your question to better illustrate what you're looking for.